# operator precedence in JavaScript : Can someone please explain why the if condition evaluates to true for all values of browser

Tags: javascript, boolean, logical-operators, operator-precedence, boolean-operations

```
if (browser == ‘chrome’||’firefox’||’safari’||’opera’)
```

Can someone please explain why the if condition evaluates to true for all values of browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the curly quotes - those will cause a SyntaxError. Use straight quotes instead.

`==` has higher operator precedence than `||`, and `||` evaluates left-to-right, so fixing the quotes, your code is equivalent to:

```
if ((((browser == 'chrome') ||'firefox') ||'safari') ||'opera')
```

If the browser is chrome, this results in

```
if ((((true) ||'firefox') ||'safari') ||'opera')
if (true)
```

Otherwise, this results in

```
if ((((false) || 'firefox') ||'safari') ||'opera')
if (((false || 'firefox') ||'safari') ||'opera')
```

If the left-hand side of `||` is falsey, it will evaluate to the value on the right-hand side. Otherwise, if the left-hand side of `||` is truthy, it will evaluate to the value on the left-hand side. So it resolves to:

```
if (((false || 'firefox') ||'safari') ||'opera')
if ((('firefox') ||'safari') ||'opera')
if ('firefox')
```

And `'firefox'` is truthy, so the `if` will always run.

For what you're trying to do, use `.includes` instead:

```
if (['chrome', 'firefox', 'safari', 'opera'].includes(browser))
```